# Hypergeometric function 1F2 in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

How can I write the Hypergeometric function 1F2 in scipy/numpy?

There was an implementation in scipy, but now it is deprecated:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.hyp1f2.html

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are searching for: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gausshyper.html#scipy.stats.gausshyper

Comment: Thanks for your comment @kvantour but that seems to be a different thing. That gives a probabilistic distribution whose normalization is related to the hypergeometric 2F1 function (not 1F2). I'm looking for an implementation of the special function 1F2.

Comment: Sorry, the only reference I found is this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8443 which just states why it has been removed and why there is no alternative.

Comment: Reading the issue which deprecates it, I see they say the implementation came from the Cephes library. Tracking that down, it seems to be implemented here: https://github.com/jeremybarnes/cephes/blob/60f27df395b8322c2da22c83751a2366b82d50d1/bessel/struve.c#L60 Only sixty lines of code - you could probably translate that to Python.

Comment: Finally I found the `mpmath` library, where that function is implemented as `hyp1f2`, with the same syntax as in the deprecated version in scipy:
https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The version in mpmath is WAY too slow for my purposes. Therefore I just packaged it separately in "Scipy Deprecated"

The code is here: https://github.com/vhaasteren/scipydepr

You can just do

```
pip install scipydepr
```

I literally just took the code & LICENSE from scipy and repackaged it. Good thing it's BSD-3.

The reason scipy deprecated it is that it wasn't universally valid and it wouldn't always converge. They decided to just ditch it, which is understandable from a maintenance perspective. For me it works though, and there was no fast way to get it.